# WCF Data Service Operation throws exception when ToList is called if no objects are returned

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

The following client method causes an InvalidOperationException if no objects are returned. The error is 'Collection types are only supported in version 3.0 of the Odata protocol.This seems like an incorrect error message.

How can one check that at least 1 object has been returned before calling ToList?  Shouldn't the call to ToList just return an empty list without throwing an exception?

```
private static void TestSearchAgentsDs(string qryString)
{
    var context = new RapDataServiceReference.RapEntities(new Uri(_svcUri));

    //Get Agents matching search criteria using WCFDS Operation
    var queryString = String.Format(
    "SearchAgents"
    + "?queryString='{0}'"
    , qryString
    );

    var result = (context.Execute<RapDataServiceReference.TvfSearchAgents_Result>(new Uri(queryString, UriKind.Relative), "GET", false));
    var agents = result.ToList();
    foreach (var agent in agents)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Agent: {0}, agent.AgentName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for null and then count greater than 0

Comment: The response is not null and there is no count property for the response.

Comment: Make sure it is collection

Comment: Side comment: It would be nice to know the type of result and agents. That's not the best place to use var.